# Append column of a timestamp-indexed dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, scipy

I have two dataframes, one of them containing historical values and another one with new values. Between both values there can be an overlap, but both are indexed with timestamps.

How can I merge both dataframes into one, without having the identical values twice (the identical values have exactly the same timestamps and values).

Thank you very much for your answers.

SAMPLE DF1

```
|2011-05-09 15:00:00|5.395|
|2011-05-09 16:00:00|7.654|
|2011-05-09 17:00:00|8.395|
|2011-05-09 18:00:00|9.999|
```

SAMPLE DF2

```
|2011-05-09 17:00:00|8.395|
|2011-05-09 18:00:00|9.999|
|2011-06-09 06:00:00|7.455|
|2011-06-09 07:00:00|7.422|
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
|2011-05-09 15:00:00|5.395|
|2011-05-09 16:00:00|7.654|
|2011-05-09 17:00:00|8.395|
|2011-05-09 18:00:00|9.999|
|2011-06-09 06:00:00|7.455|
|2011-06-09 07:00:00|7.422|
```

Comment: please provide sample data and expected output.  You can use `df.to_dict()` for example if they're small enough

Comment: its very big numbers, so the data will look quite ugly here in text form, but i can explain. lets say i got a lot of temperature values from the last 10 years as df1, but they were last updated 7 days ago.. so my df2 are all the new values from the last 7 days.. the overlap of the values is day 7.  my expected output df should have all values from df1 and df2 but no overlap. i hope it helps.

Comment: i edited my post with simplified numbers to explain the logic of the data merge. im still a beginner with pandas, hope that its clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is concatenate and dedupe:

```
pd.concat([DF1,DF2]).drop_duplicates()
```

assuming `import pandas as pd`

Comment: @SergeBallesta good point, edited my answer

Comment: This. Would have done it exactly like this.